# Why linq to xml fails to select child nodes without explicit cardinality constraint?

Tags: linq-to-xml

There is an xml file with the following structure

```
....
<workDomain>                      
...
<event>some value</event>
.....
    <event>
        <code codeContainer="CCVal1" code="4567">
        ...
        <code>
    </event>
</workDomain>
```

I am interested in the event with code children, not the simple event without any code children.

However, if I use the following linq query:

```
var res = from node in xDoc.Descendants(nsohr + "workDomain").Single().Descendants(nsohr + "event")
                      where node.Descendants(nsohr + "code").Single().Attribute("codeContainer").Value.Equals("CCVal1")
                      && node.Descendants(nsohr + "code").Single().Attribute("code").Value.Equals("4567")
                      select node;
```

returns nothing. That is I get: "Sequence contains no elements" exception if I attempt to iterate over res with foreach.

If I enforce the existence of children of event through an explicit constraint such as the one below:

```
var res = from node in xDoc.Descendants(nsohr + "workDomain").Single().Descendants(nsohr + "event")
                      where node.Descendants(nsohr + "code").Count() > 0
                      && node.Descendants(nsohr + "code").Single().Attribute("codeContainer").Value.Equals("CCVal1")
                      && node.Descendants(nsohr + "code").Single().Attribute("code").Value.Equals("4567")
                      select node;
```

Then everything works as expected. Why on earth do I have to add

`node.Descendants(nsohr + "code").Count() > 0` ? The constrains on descendants should imply their existence, or so I think. This feels very unnatural to me. What am I missing here?

**Update:**
Jon's example helped me see my misunderstanding about the way linq to xml works. I was somehow under the impression that the criteria I've placed on the nodes would determine the nodes which will be selected (incorrectly) thinking things work like a db query:  db parsing sql and selecting data etc...
I simply ended up calling methods on wrong objects for calling those methods.
Jon's snippet with a small fix (assuming I'm not missing something here Jon) works as expected:

```
var res = xDoc.Descendants(nsohr + "workDomain")
              .Descendants(nsohr + "event")
              .Where(x => x.Elements("code")
                           .Any(y => (string) y.Attribute("codeContainer") == "CCVal1"
                                  && (string) y.Attribute("code") == "4567"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Returns nothing" and "I get an exception" are *very* different.

The problem is here:

```
 where node.Descendants(nsohr + "code")
           .Single().Attribute("codeContainer").Value.Equals("CCVal1")
```

You're using `Single()`, which is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) to throw an exception if there isn't exactly one element. And sure enough, you've got that exception.

Your query can be made much simpler though:

```
var res = xDoc.Descendants(nsohr + "workDomain")
              .Descendants(nsohr + "event")
              .Where(x => x.Elements("code")
                           .Any(x => (string) x.Attribute("codeContainer") == "CCVal1"
                                  && (string) x.Attribute("code") == "4567"));
```

(That's assuming that `code` is always a direct child of `event`; if it's not, you could use `Descendants` instead of `Elements`.)

In other words, find `event` descendants of `workDomain` elements, where at least one child `code` child element has the relevant attributes.

Comment: Thanks Jon, the sample query really helped. I've also rephrased the returns nothing and exception bits in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.Single()` on a collection with a number of elements other than 1, you will always get an exception.

`node.Descendants(nsohr + "code").Single()` is the segment that's probably throwing the exception.

If your collection is not (in theory) supposed to only have 1 element, than you should not use `.Single()`

You've apparently found a query that works for you though.  are there any other problems with it?

---

for future reference, if you're only seeking 1 of an element, you can use methods like `Element` or `Descendant`.

You can also call `Elements` and `Descendants` on collections of elements.